# When creating a NuGet package, can I modify existing source code files?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to create a series of NuGet packages for local use within my organization.

I'm aware I can create source-code transformation files (i.e. **MyModel.cs.pp**) to help with adding **new** source code files, i.e.:

```
namespace $rootnamespace$.Models {
    public struct CategoryInfo {
        public string categoryid;
        public string description;
    }
}
```

But what if I want to modify an existing source-code file? Is there any way to do this? Perhaps using PowerShell?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901954/can-nuget-edit-a-config-file-or-only-add-to-it

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using CodeModel http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codemodel.aspx.

Comment: Can you point us at a simple example that uses the Code Model from within a NuGet package?

Comment: @Simon Gill It's not pretty:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/13255356/11635 I used the related answer I cited on the question