# Nuget package to insert project name in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, nuget-package

I've created a Nuget package which inserts a key/value pair called `ApplicationName` in the `web.config` file with a default value of `Application Name`.

Is there a way to get the name of the .Net MVC project that a user would be installing the package into the value of the key/value in a human readable format? i.e. Incorrect: <s>`ApplicationName`</s> Correct: `Application Name`

If it's not possible to get the project name, I suppose using some sort of command line option could work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days of pondering, here is the solution I came up with.

1. Create a `web.config` transform file to add the key/value pair to the `AppSettings` section.
2. Create an `install.ps1` file, that grabs the project name, parses it and injects the new value for `AppplicationName` in the `web.config`.

Here's my `web.config.install.xdt` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <add key="ApplicationName" value="Application Name" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here's is my `install.ps1` script:

```
# Runs every time a package is installed in a project
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

# $installPath is the path to the folder where the package is installed.
# $toolsPath is the path to the tools directory in the folder where the package is installed.
# $package is a reference to the package object.
# $project is a reference to the project the package was installed to.

$p = Get-Project
$project_readable_name = ($p.Name -creplace  '([A-Z\W_]|\d+)(?<![a-z])',' $&').trim()

# Solution based on answer found on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901954/can-nuget-edit-a-config-file-or-only-add-to-it
$xml = New-Object xml

# Find the web.config 
$config = $project.ProjectItems | where {$_.Name -eq "Web.config"}

if($config) {
    # Find web.config's path on the file system
    $localPath = $config.Properties | where {$_.Name -eq "LocalPath"}

    # Load Web.config as XML
    $xml.Load($localPath.Value)

    # Select the ApplicationName node
    $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("configuration/appSettings/add[@key='ApplicationName']")

    # Change the ApplicationName value
    $node.SetAttribute("value", $project_readable_name)

    # Save the Web.config file
    $xml.Save($localPath.Value)
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else!