# Can I get the location of the packages folder for the current solution when applying an xdt?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore, xdt-transform

I want to install a design time plugin for a visual studio extension (ie runs when using visual studio, and not when the application is running). This requires that I modify the app.config with an entry that points at the dll containing the extension code. The plugin is installed via nuget and if I add this dll to a folder under the project and use a fixed path in the app.config.install.xdt then everything work ok. However what I want is for the xdt to insert a value which points to the dll in the packages folder, where it gets installed via nuget. My problem is that the relative path to the nuget folder is not fixed for the projects. Each project may be in a different folder (several folders deep inside the solution folder) and not just in a direct child of the solution folder, so I want to be able to use some variable in my xdt.

Currently I have this in my xdt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <specFlow>
    <plugins xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <add name="NCrunch.Generator" path=".\SpecflowPlugins\" type="Generator" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </plugins>
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

but I want something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <specFlow>
    <plugins xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <add name="NCrunch.Generator" path="$(SolutionDir)\packages\Specflow.Ncrunch.1.0.0\lib\net" type="Generator" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </plugins>
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

is this possible in xdt? if not is there another option for getting this to munge the app.config correctly when my nuget package installs?

Answer (score 0):

The XDT syntax doesn't allow replacement tokens such as the one you put in your example.

One option I can think of would be to modify the **app.config.install.xdt** file in your **init.ps1** PowerShell script, replacing the tokens for the actual values before the XDT transform is applied by NuGet.

For more information regarding init.ps1 see: [Creating and Publishing a Package](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package)

Comment: I like that idea, thanks. I'll try it and see what I can do.

Comment: I finally got around to trying this and even if I modify the app.config.install.xdt file it seems to use the unmodified version when it is applied it seems. My app.config is changed, but using the original values, even thouigh when I open the app.config.install.xdt file from the packages folder for the solution it contains my new values.  Oh well looks like I'll have to [modify it in the install.ps1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8449741/97614) instead.