# Modify (or add) existing methods/events

Tags: powershell, nuget, global-asax

I'm trying to write a Powershell script to modify the global.asax.cs file during installation of a NUGET package.

Specifically, I wish to add a line of code to the `Application_Start` event, and I also wish to add several lines of code to the `Application_BeginRequest` event - if the `Application_BeginRequest` event doesn't exist then I need to add it.

I'd prefer not to use WebActivator to do something similar because I'd prefer not to add another dependency if this can be achieved through Powershell.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242282/nuget-powershell-script-to-modify-global-asax-cs) to be quite helpful in demonstrating how to replace the contents of the global.asax, but it wouldn't be a very popular NUGET package if it completely replaced the contents, so is there perhaps a way in which I can build a template global.asax.cs inside the NUGET package which instructs Powershell which parts to insert?

Comment: global.asax is just an XML file, and you can manipulate XML files with PowerShell the same way you do in a compiled .NET app.

Comment: It's the events in the global.asax.cs file that I wish to add code to. The global.asax file (the XML instance) has nothing more than a declaration which references the code-file, so manipulating the XML instance of the file doesn't achieve what I want.

Comment: Then you need to be more specific in your post about what file(s) you need to modify.